# How to form predicate with complex keyPath?

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

I am trying to set an NSFetchedResultsController for menuItems for restaurantId 21.
Each MenuItem has a Section (To One)
Each Section has a Menu (To One)
Each Menu has a restaurant (To One)
Each restaurant has an Int64 restaurantId

I am getting no objects for the following NSPredicate.

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MenuItem")
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "section.menu.restaurant.restaurantId == 21")
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "section", ascending: true)]
```

`po menuItem.section!.menu!.restaurant!.restaurantId!` gives me 21 in the debugger if I don't attach the predicate an list all menuItems.

What's wrong with my predicate?

Comment: What type is a `restaurantId` property have? If it is a string type, then use `'21'` instead of `21`.

Comment: How are you sorting on the section object? Is that an exact copy of your code?

Comment: restaurantId is Int64.

Comment: I use one more sortDescriptor but that should be inconsequential.
If I remove the predicate, everything displays just fine. `fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "section", ascending: true),
    NSSortDescriptor(key: "itemID", ascending: true)]` The exact code for your reference.